# No job show up in Runs page while trying to run a Chainlink node locally

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I am trying to fulfil requests on my local test chainlink node on rinkeby (following https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/) but can't see any job runs appear on my operator ui.

The Oracle contract is at [0xA66f738a4688A9E51c2c6FF901CC3B11ce31AE6C](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xA66f738a4688A9E51c2c6FF901CC3B11ce31AE6C)

The ATestnetConsumer contract is at [0x977129EE2f404F4327A2A60C5fD9E57890D85FD0](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x977129ee2f404f4327a2a60c5fd9e57890d85fd0)

My job toml screenshot below
[image]

Have confirmed my .env that it is running the rinkeby wss url from infura and the chain is 4 and the link token contract address is 0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709

My node wallet has ETH and LINK. Both the contracts have Link too (but no ETH).

I run the setFulfillmentPermission function in remix with my Node wallet address and true

[image]

When I execute the requestEthereumPrice function with my oracle address and job id, I can see the LINK being sent by the [ATestnetConsumer contract to the Oracle contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xd1b71dd8ec83b7e204de5d2d0a95fdde2be41d0eadb181231ee21596ef661f78) but no job run gets created in my local Chainlink node.

[image]

Confirming that the job hasn't run, I get the 0 value when I run the currentPrice function on ATestnetConsumer.

Can anyone please point me to where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work. Posting my two findings as I do think the documentation needs an update to account for these.

1. The external job id in the Jobs screen on the Operator UI has dashes in them. To use them in the ATestnetConsumer contract you need to remove the dashes (so 0e84f38985eb4edb98c2e2a09b589666 and not 0e84f389-85eb-4edb-98c2-e2a09b589666).
2. The direct request toml doesn't seem to work as is. I had to append allowunrestrictednetworkaccess="true" to the fetch section so it becomes

   fetch        [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.get)" allowunrestrictednetworkaccess="true"]